# Drawing an edge around an arc using SWT

Tags: java, graphics, swt

I am attempting to draw an edge around an arc drawn using SWT graphics, the curved edge itself works very well because it uses the SWT draw arc too, but when it comes to drawing the straight edges I am using some trig to work out where to join the lines up and unfortunately, due to I guess a rounding error that I can't spot, or some mystery of the draw arc function, I can't get this to work when the width of the shape (in degrees) is an odd number. You can see the edges just don't line up, I've tried to play around and have included a reproducible version of my code here:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner;

public class ArcDialog extends Dialog {

    private Color blue;

    public ArcDialog(final Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(final Shell shell) {

    blue = new Color(shell.getDisplay(), new RGB(0, 100, 255));
    super.configureShell(shell);
    shell.setSize(new Point(450, 550));
    shell.setText("Arc Edges"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public Control createDialogArea(final Composite comp) {

    final Composite content = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(comp);
    final Composite parent = new Composite(content, SWT.NONE);

    final GridLayout gridLayout2 = new GridLayout(6, false);
    parent.setLayout(gridLayout2);
    parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Direction");

    Spinner direction = new Spinner(parent, SWT.NONE);

    direction.setMaximum(360);
    direction.setMinimum(0);
    direction.setIncrement(1);
    direction.setSelection(0);

    new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Width");

    Spinner width = new Spinner(parent, SWT.NONE);
    width.setMaximum(270);
    width.setMinimum(5);
    width.setSelection(65);
    width.setIncrement(1);

    new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Length");

    Spinner length = new Spinner(parent, SWT.NONE);
    length.setMaximum(200);
    length.setMinimum(10);
    length.setIncrement(1);
    length.setSelection(150);

    final Canvas c = new Canvas(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    c.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 6, 0));
    c.addPaintListener(e -> {
        e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
        drawArc(e.gc, (double) direction.getSelection(), new Point(c.getSize().x / 2, c.getSize().y / 2),
            length.getSelection(), width.getSelection());
        drawArcEdges(e.gc, (double) direction.getSelection(), new Point(c.getSize().x / 2, c.getSize().y / 2),
            length.getSelection(), width.getSelection());
    });

    length.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> c.redraw());
    width.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> c.redraw());
    direction.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> c.redraw());

    return content;
    }

    protected void drawArc(final GC gc, final Double b, final Point screenLocation, final int length,
        final double arcWidth) {

    if (length > 0) {

        gc.setBackground(blue);
        gc.fillArc(screenLocation.x - length, screenLocation.y - length, length * 2, length * 2,
            (int) Math.round(90 - (b - (arcWidth / 2))), (int) Math.round(-arcWidth));

    }
    }

    protected void drawArcEdges(final GC gc, final Double b, final Point screenLocation, final int length,
        final double arcWidth) {

    if (length > 0) {
        Point edge = getFinalLocation(screenLocation, (double) Math.round((b - (arcWidth / 2))), length);
        gc.setLineStyle(SWT.LINE_DASH);

        gc.drawLine(screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y, edge.x, edge.y);
        edge = getFinalLocation(screenLocation, (double) Math.round(b + (arcWidth / 2)), length);

        gc.drawLine(screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y, edge.x, edge.y);

        gc.drawArc(screenLocation.x - length, screenLocation.y - length, length * 2, length * 2,
            (int) Math.round(90 - (b - (arcWidth / 2))), (int) Math.round(-arcWidth));

    }
    }

    protected Point getFinalLocation(final Point start, final Double angle, final int length) {

    final int newX = (int) Math.floor((start.x + (length * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))) + 0.5));
    final int newY = (int) Math.floor(((start.y - (length * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)))) + 0.5));
    return new Point(newX, newY);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new Display();

    final ArcDialog fml = new ArcDialog(new Shell());
    fml.open();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a rounding error.

When you call `getFinalLocation`, simply replace the `Math.rounds` to `Math.floor`:

```
Point edge = getFinalLocation(screenLocation, Math.floor(b - (arcWidth / 2)), length);
...
edge = getFinalLocation(screenLocation, Math.floor(b + (arcWidth / 2)), length);
```

The alignment looks much better.

Comment: This does seem to have sorted it out.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing the math yourself you could use [Eclipse GEF](https://www.eclipse.org/gef/) to correctly draw the arc outline.

**To draw the whole outline:**

With GEF you can create a `Pie` (which is the outline of an arc) and convert it to a SWT `PathData` that you can entirely draw with `gc.drawPath`.

`drawArcEdges` then becomes:

```
protected void drawArcEdges(final GC gc, final Double b, final Point screenLocation, final int length,
                            final double arcWidth) {

    if (length > 0) {
        gc.setLineStyle(SWT.LINE_DASH);

        Pie pie = new Pie(screenLocation.x - length, screenLocation.y - length, length * 2, length * 2,
                Angle.fromDeg((int) Math.round(90 - (b - (-arcWidth / 2)))), Angle.fromDeg((int) Math.round(arcWidth)));

        PathData arcSwtPathData = Geometry2SWT.toSWTPathData(pie.toPath());
        Path arcSwtPath = new Path(gc.getDevice(), arcSwtPathData);

        gc.drawPath(arcSwtPath);

        arcSwtPath.dispose();
    }
}
```

**To draw the outline in different parts:**

With GEF you can create an `Arc` and retrieve its starting (X1,Y1) and ending (X2,Y2) points.

Using these points you can then separately draw the lines and the arc with `gc`.

`drawArcEdges` then becomes:

```
protected void drawArcEdges(final GC gc, final Double b, final Point screenLocation, final int length,
                            final double arcWidth) {

    if (length > 0) {
        gc.setLineStyle(SWT.LINE_DASH);

        Arc arc = new Arc(screenLocation.x - length, screenLocation.y - length, length * 2, length * 2,
                Angle.fromDeg((int) Math.round(90 - (b - (-arcWidth / 2)))), Angle.fromDeg((int) Math.round(arcWidth)));

        gc.drawLine(screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y, (int)arc.getX1(), (int)arc.getY1());
        gc.drawLine(screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y, (int)arc.getX2(), (int)arc.getY2());

        gc.drawArc(screenLocation.x - length, screenLocation.y - length, length * 2, length * 2,
                (int) Math.round(90 - (b - (arcWidth / 2))), (int) Math.round(-arcWidth));
    }
}
```

**To use GEF:**

To use GEF you should just need to include the following jars:

```
org.eclipse.gef.geometry.convert.swt.Geometry2SWT<version>.jar
org.eclipse.gef.geometry<version>.jar
```

You can retrieve them in the "plugin" folder from the builds here: https://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/index.php.

Choose the latest version and click on the update site link to download the full zip.

Comment: Can you draw different Line styles for different parts, and optionally have parts on / off?

Comment: @Link19 not directly, I've added another method in the answer to draw the parts separately.